# Xerox WorkCenter 3025 printer stopped printing over Wi-Fi after updating to Ubunru 23.04

Tags: printing, 23.04

After updating to Ubuntu 23.04 my Xerox WorkCenter 3025 Wi-Fi printer stopped printing over Wi-Fi.

How to fix this?